# How to change arrow head width and length of CurveB in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create annotations with an arrow with the code given below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
figure = plt.figure(figsize=(5.15, 5.15))
figure.clf()
plot = plt.subplot(111)
plot.set_xlabel(r'\textit{X}', labelpad=6)
plot.set_ylabel(r'\textit{Y}', labelpad=6)
plt.annotate(r'\textit{P}', xy = (0.5, 0.5),  \
    xycoords = 'data', xytext = (0.4, 0.4), \
    textcoords = 'data', fontsize = 7, arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle = "->"))
plt.show()
```

I tried to change the head width and head length as follows:

```
arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle = "->", head_width = 0.2, head_length = 0.1)
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'FancyArrowPatch' object has no attribute 'set_head_width'
```

How to change the head length, head width and body width in matplotlib?

Answer (score 0):

Use *headwidth* and *frac* to specify width and length of the arrowhead. 
*frac* is the the headlength written as fraction from total arrow length.

```
plt.annotate(r'\textit{P}', xy = (0.5, 0.5),  \
    xycoords = 'data', xytext = (0.4, 0.4), \
    textcoords = 'data', fontsize = 7, arrowprops=dict(headwidth = 15, frac = 0.5))
```